# How to display the name

Tags: android, android-sqlite

How can i display the name after the user if done inputting the name because i dont know how to do it yet and insert the data in the database.

I want to display the name and be able to add a time and date alarm.

How can i display the name after the user if done inputting the name because i dont know how to do it yet and insert the data in the database.

I want to display the name and be able to add a time and date alarm.

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private EditText edtName;

    Spinner spin1;
    Spinner spin2;
    Spinner spin3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(); 


        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.bar);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        edtName = findViewById(R.id.edtName);

        spin1 = findViewById(R.id.spinnerFrequency);
        spin2 = findViewById(R.id.SpinnerTime);
        spin3 = findViewById(R.id.SpinnerQty);

        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        /*screen*/
        adapter.AddFragment(new Drugfragment(), "Drug");
        adapter.AddFragment(new Appointmentfragment(), "Appointment");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);




        Account c = new Account();
        if(c==null) {

        }else{
           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("LOG IN");
            LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.account,null));
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                    LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();


                                    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.accountname,null));
                                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                        }
                                    });


                                    builder.show();
                                }
                            });



            builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });

            builder.show();

            db.insertRecord();

        }

    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }


}
```

This is my db helper

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by User on 23/5/2018.
 */

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="accountDB.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="Account";
    private static final String COL1="AccountName";
    private static final String COL2="Time";

    public DBHelper(){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table Account(acctname text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        this.onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertRecord(AccountInfo a){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contents = new ContentValues();

        contents.put("AccountName", a.getAcctName());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic principle of retrieving and then utilising data stored in an SQLiteDatabase on an Android device, is to use/run a **query** to **SELECT** the data, which is made available via a **Cursor** and to then **move** within the Cursor to the appropriate row or rows and to finally extract the data from the respective column or columns.

For your specific issue you want to find the last inserted row and fortunately SQLite has a function that that assists, that is the `last_insert_rowid()`

So the query would be `SELECT * FROM Account WHERE rowid = last_insert_rowid()`

As there are various issues with the code that you have supplied. The following is an example, based upon your code, that will :-

1. Add a new Account (albeit a very basic one with just a name) and then
2. Extract the name of the last Account that was added (albeit that as you know the name this isn't very useful at all).

   - Note this is very limited but shows a technique.
   - Note rowid is a special column that is by default provided for every row (a WITHOUT ROWID table would not have a rowid). **rowid** uniquely identifies a row and is a integer initially 1, then likely 2 and then likely 3....... BUT it should never be relied upon as increasing monotonically.

First a very Simple `AccountInfo` Class namely AccountInfo.java (which you already appear to have :-

```
public class AccountInfo {

    private String mAccountName;

    public AccountInfo(String account_name) {
        this.mAccountName = account_name;
    }
    public String getAcctName() {
        return mAccountName;
    }
}
```

Second **DBHelper.java** (note comments, also not how similar it is to yours) :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="accountDB.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="Account";
    private static final String COL1="AccountName"; //<<<< not used
    private static final String COL2="Time"; //<<<< not used

    public DBHelper(Context context){ //<<<< modifed to include the Context to be passed
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< This is superfluous and isn't used in this example >>>>>>>>>>
    //<<<<<<<<<< It could be deleted                                >>>>>>>>>>
    public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table Account(acctname text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        this.onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertRecord(AccountInfo a){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contents = new ContentValues();
        //contents.put("AccountName", a.getAcctName()); //<<<< Will fail as incorrect column name
        contents.put("acctname",a.getAcctName()); //<<<< column name as per table definition
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,contents); //<<<< ADDED to do the insert itself
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< The Query that gets the name of the account last added >>>>>>>>>>
    public String getLastInsertedAccountName() {
        String rv = ""; //<<<< Just in case nothing is extracted set the return value to empty String
        String[] columns = new String[]{"acctname"}; //<<<< The columns to extract (only one)
        String whereclause = "rowid = last_insert_rowid()"; //<<<< The SQL WHERE clause (less the WHERE keyword)
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();//<<<< Get the SQLite database
        // Use the SQLliteDatabase convenience query method that gets the data into a Cursor
        Cursor csr = db.query(
                DATABASE_TABLE, //<<<< The table to be queried (ie FROM )
                columns, //<<<< The columns to be returned just one (could use null to return all columns)
                whereclause, //<<<< The WHERE clause
                null, //<<<< selection args (none so null)
                null, //<<<< the column(s) to GROUP BY (none so null)
                null, //<<<< The having clause (none so null)
                null //<<<< The ORDER BY clause (none so null)
        );
        //<<<< Move to the first (only) row in the Cursor (if there is one)
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            // Get the value, as a string, from the column name acctname
            rv = csr.getString(
                    csr.getColumnIndex(
                            "acctname"
                    )
            );
        }
        csr.close(); //<<<< Close the Cursor as done with it
        return rv; //<<<< Finally retruned that extracted value
    }
}
```

The Invoking code in the activity, **MainActivity** (very simple) :-

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DBHelper mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this); //<<<< Get an instance of the DBHelper
    AccountInfo c = new AccountInfo("Fred"); //<<<< Create an Account to add
    mDBHlpr.insertRecord(c);
    //<<<<<<<<<< one line version of the two lines above (commented out) <<<<<<<<<<
    //mDBHlpr.insertRecord(new AccountInfo("Tom"));

    String account_just_inserted = mDBHlpr.getLastInsertedAccountName(); //<<<< get the name

    //<<<<<<<<<< Do something with the name i.e. write it out to the Log >>>>>>>>>>
    Log.d(
            "ACCOUNT INSERTED",
            "The Name of the account just inserted is :-" +
                    account_just_inserted
    );
}
```

}

- **Note** each time the App is run, a new row, with Fred as the account name will be added.

#### Result

running the above will output something similar to :-

> ```
> 05-24 09:27:14.215 1287-1287/acnta.accountapp D/ACCOUNT INSERTED: The Name of the account just inserted is :-Fred
> ```

Comment: how to get for example 
name = edtName.getText().toString() ;
DBHelper mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
AccountInfo a = new AccountInfo(name);

dont work it makes my app force close

Comment: sir can you help me?